# metrics.precison_score-TypeError: len() of unsized object

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn.metric.precision,but it always report the error:'TypeError: len() of unsized object',can anyone help?

```
true = np.zeros((392, 45))
pred = np.zeros((392, 45))
print(precision_score(true,pred,average='micro'))
y_pred=np.loadtxt('y_pre.txt',delimiter=',')
y_true=np.loadtxt('y_true.txt',delimiter=',')
print(true.shape,pre.shape)
print(y_true.shape,y_pred.shape)
print(precision_score(y_true,y_pred,average='micro'))
```

If I just initialize two arrays like 'true' and 'pred' for precision_score,it won't report the error.But while I using my array 'y_true' and 'y_pred',they have the same shape with (392,45).I don't why this error comes.

Comment: Are your true labels one-hot-encoded and your predictions probabilities? According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) the inputs to `precision_score` should be 1d arrays.

Comment: 2d array is ok in for multilabel.And there are just 1 and -1 in 'y_pred' and 'y_true'

Comment: thans,I solved this error by changing the value -1 in array to 0